# How to calculate this limit related to hypergeometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, hypergeometric-function

**How to calculate this limit**

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} np^n \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} \frac1k \binom{k-1}{n-1} (1-p)^{k-n}
,\quad\,where\;0<p<1
$$

Comment: the sum neesd to be from k=1 to n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|z|<1$, using the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases), we have $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{k-1}{n-1}\frac{z^k}{k}=\int_0^z\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{k-1}{n-1}x^{k-1}\,dx=\int_0^z\frac{x^{n-1}\,dx}{(1-x)^n}=\int_0^{z/(1-z)}\frac{y^{n-1}\,dy}{1+y},$$ the last equality is after substituting $x=y/(1+y)$. Thus, if $a:=(1-p)/p$, the given limit is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{a^n}\int_0^a\frac{y^{n-1}\,dy}{1+y}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{1+a}}_{=p}+\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^a\frac{(y/a)^n}{(1+y)^2}\,dy}_{=0}$$ (after integration by parts). Thus, the answer is simply $\color{blue}{p}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the formula is
$$S_n= n\,p^n \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} \frac1k\, \binom{k-1}{n-1} \,(1-p)^{k-n}$$
$$S_n=n\,p^n\,\frac{\, _2F_1(n,n;n+1;1-p)}{n}=p^n\, _2F_1(n,n;n+1;1-p)$$ which rewrite
$$S_n=p \, _2F_1(1,1;n+1;1-p)$$ which *seems* to tend to $p$.

Computed for $n=10^4$ with limited precision
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_{10000} \\
 0.1 & 0.100009 \\
 0.2 & 0.200016 \\
 0.3 & 0.300021 \\
 0.4 & 0.400024 \\
 0.5 & 0.500025 \\
 0.6 & 0.600024 \\
 0.7 & 0.700021 \\
 0.8 & 0.800016 \\
 0.9 & 0.900009
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: "...which seems..." - it surely does ;)

Comment: @metamorphy. I have not been able to find the asymptotics of  $\, _2F_1(1,1;n+1;1-p)$ for large $n$. Do you know it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: I think it is visible directly from the defining series for $_2F_1$ (all terms, except the first one, vanish in the limit).

Comment: @metamorphy is correct. The Gauss series is a generalised asymptotic expansion for large $c$ of $F(a,b;c;z)$. See http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.ii

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for the link ! I missed it once more. Cheers :-)